# Auditing a many-to-many join with a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I have some entities that have relationships as follows:
[Simplified ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzslT.png)

The join tables all have additional fields (not shown).

I am having difficulty auditing the joins for the OrderOutletProducts.

My attempt:

OutletProduct

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class OutletProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OutletProductPk pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("outletId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "outlet_id")
    private Outlet outlet;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "outletProduct")
    private Set<OrderOutletProduct> orderOutletProducts = new HashSet<OrderOutletProduct>();
}
```

OutletProductPk

```
@Embeddable
public class OutletProductPk implements Serializable { 

    @Column(name = "outletId")
    private Long outletId;

    @Column(name = "productId")
    private Long productId;

    // equals, hashcode, etc...
}
```

OrderOutletProduct

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class OrderOutletProduct {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderOutletProductPk pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("orderId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("outletProductPk")
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "outlet_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
    })
    private OutletProduct outletProduct;
}
```

OrderOutletProductPk

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderOutletProductPk implements Serializable { 

    private Long orderId;

    private OutletProductPk outletProductPk;

    // equals, hashcode, etc...
}
```

This results in:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
[...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported: org.hibernate.type.ComponentType
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addIdProperties(IdMetadataGenerator.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addId(IdMetadataGenerator.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:632)
        at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:875)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:340)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
        ... 59 more
```

The presence of envers in the stack trace led me to try removing `@Audited`, but that attempt was met with complaints of an unaudited entity joined to an audited one, and while de-auditing my whole schema eliminates the bug, is out of the question for my requirements.

I am using Hibernate 5.1.12.Final with the corresponding Envers.

Edit: The problem appears to be the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107452/having-difficulty-using-envers-to-audit-a-many-to-many-relation).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the column's names. In OutletProductPK you use

```
@Column(name = "outletId")
private Long outletId;

@Column(name = "productId")
private Long productId;
```

and in the other classes you use product_id and outlet_id. What are the names in the columns on you database?

Comment: Good eye, but my naming strategy remaps camelCase to snake_case. Plus, the OutletProduct object works fine on its own—only when joined again do I have issues.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the `@JoinColumn` annotations, the `@Audit` annotations, and rename the `Order` table to `Orders` everything seems to build okay. So it doesn't seem to be a `JPA` specific error at the root of it. `Order` is a SQL reserved keyword. These specific `@JoinColumn` annotations

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "outlet_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
})
```

gave me a validation error in Eclipse.

> Referenced column name must be specified when there are multiple join columns

The output.

```
Hibernate: create table OrderOutletProduct (order_id bigint not null, outletProduct_outlet_id bigint not null, outletProduct_product_id bigint not null, primary key (order_id, outletProduct_outlet_id, outletProduct_product_id))
Hibernate: create table Orders (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table Outlet (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table OutletProduct (outlet_id bigint not null, product_id bigint not null, primary key (outlet_id, product_id))
Hibernate: create table Product (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table OrderOutletProduct add constraint FK31ytkakdnwf3mvw7p6paij7u6 foreign key (order_id) references Orders
Hibernate: alter table OrderOutletProduct add constraint FKjsywutttlonx76evhm9b0kk02 foreign key (outletProduct_outlet_id, outletProduct_product_id) references OutletProduct
Hibernate: alter table OutletProduct add constraint FKi0nyyoj3d031g0sn6gkutbxn5 foreign key (outlet_id) references Outlet
Hibernate: alter table OutletProduct add constraint FKr3s09f6ofstlb1qomfwfjsjwy foreign key (product_id) references Produc
```

So, I suggest starting there and adding things in slowly be sure you understand how the annotations are meant to function until you can be more specific in any error or problem you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the problem appears to be the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107452/having-difficulty-using-envers-to-audit-a-many-to-many-relation), as removing the auditing fixes the problem.

Comment: Pretty much what I said.